# Load data from service and pass to child component using @Input

Tags: angular

I consume my custom `DataService` angular service to get some strongly-typed `MultiLanguageText` data which I save in my `phrase` field. I then would like to pass it to the child component using `@Input`.

I tried loading the data at the `ngOnInit` and also `ngOnChanges` lifecycle (see code) hook, but my child component would receive `undefined` in both cases.

When hardcoding the `phrase` value, it would work, which tells me, the data is loaded from the service AFTER I already sent an `undefined` value to the child component.

**relevant types**

```
export class MultiLanguageText {
  de: string;
  fr: string;
  en: string;
}
```

**parent template:**

```
<child-component [phrase]="this.phrase">
</child-component>
```

**parent component code:**

```
/* imports & meta data omitted for readability */

export class ParentComponent implements OnChanges {

  phrase: MultiLanguageText;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.dataService.getData().then((d) => {
      this.phrase = d;
      console.log(this.phrase); // logs correct data
    });
  }
}
```

**child template:**

```
<p>{{this.phrase.en}}</p>
```

**child component code:**

```
/* imports & meta data omitted for readability */

export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() phrase: MultiLanguageText;

  constructor() {
    console.log("phrase equals: ", this.phrase); // logs `undefined`, why?
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1: ADDED `ngOnChanges` HOOK TO CHILD COMPONENT:**

**child component code:**

```
/* imports & meta data omitted for readability */

export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() phrase: MultiLanguageText;

  constructor() {
    console.log("phrase equals: ", this.phrase); // logs `undefined`
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    console.log("phrase equals: ", this.phrase); // logs correct data, yay!
  }
}
```

So far so good, I can now access the correct data from the child component's controller. However, in the template it's still using the "original" `undefined` value, how can I force the template to use the newly available valid data?

**UPDATE 2: USE METHOD TO GET `phrase.en` DATA**

As pointed out by @Riron, the `phrase` variable is set asynchronously, so when the children are constructed, the value of `phrase` is still `undefined`.
As soon as the `phrase` data would be loaded, it could be used in the template. My approach to solve this was using a method in the controller:

```
getPhrase = () => {
    return this.phrase === undefined ? "" : this.phrase.en;
}
```

Which I then would call from the template:

```
<p>{{ getPhrase() }}</p>
```

Comment: You need to implement `OnChanges` on `MotivationalDriversFormComponent` too and check for changes in its `ngOnChanges` life-cycle hook.

Comment: @echonax thanks for the comment, would you mind clearifying your point using a code example? I'm not sure how this would look like.

Comment: It's just like your `ParentComponent` just implement the `ngOnChanges` to it like Riron's answer

Comment: @echonax thanks, yes that's works, however, I still don't understand how I can now inform the template that the valid value is available

Comment: Inform which template?

Comment: It's Angular question, not AngularJS one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Riron, the `phrase` variable is set asynchronously, so when the children are constructed, the value of `phrase` is still `undefined`.
As soon as the `phrase` data would be loaded, it could be used in the template. My approach to solve this was using a method in the controller:

```
getPhrase = () => {
    return this.phrase === undefined ? "" : this.phrase.en;
}
```

Which I then would call from the template:

```
<p>{{ getPhrase() }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `phrase` variable is set asynchronously, so when the children is constructed, the value of `phrase` is still `undefined`.

If you implement `ngOnChanges` on the child component instead of the parent, you should see the value coming at some point (not on first check though) :

```
export class MotivationalDriversFormComponent {

  @Input() phrase: MultiLanguageText;

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("phrase equals: ", this.phrase);
  }
}
```

And

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnChanges {

  phrase: MultiLanguageText;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getData().then((d) => {
      this.phrase = d;
      console.log(this.phrase); // logs correct data
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Riron this helps a bit, however, the template still won't display the valid value after it's available (please also consider my updated question).

Comment: Did you remove the `this` in your templates ? You only need them in your JS code

Comment: @Riron you should edit your answer with removing the `this` from the template to show OP what you mean.

Comment: @Riron @echonax Yes I did remove the `this`. Sry, the mistake was that I omitted too much in my OP. In my child template I evaluated `{{phrase.en}}` and at first, when `phrase` still would be `undefined`, there would no `en` property be on it. I solved it using a getter instead: `getPhrase = () => { return this.phrase === undefined ? "" : this.phrase[this.language]; }`
Sorry for the confusion, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

1) you dont need to use this when you using parameter from the component.

```
 <child-component [phrase]="this.phrase"></child-component>
```

2) the same is for binding.

```
<p>{{phrase}}</p>
```

Comment: while the point you made is true, it hasn't to do anything with the question asked. thanks anyway